# xml id's in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, xml

I know they changed how the constants in the resources class are stored in ADT 14 but how do I then get the `id` of an xml item since `r.id.item` gives an error now?

for example this gives me an error

```
mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is this in a library? they've only changed in library projects, edit: what error?

Comment: its not a logcat error, I cant compile. error says `id cannot be resolved or is not a field` I am trying to test the fragment pager support example http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest there is a different problem or you should clean your projects.

http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14

Implies that the only problems you should encounter are using Id's for switches in library projects.

My personal experience is that things are fine (even in library projects, except switch)

Past some code or an error to get more help

Comment: `id cannot be resolved or is not a field` I am trying to test the fragment pager support example http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html